# Reemplazar correctamente cada uno de los elementos de una lista dentro de una string

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

¿Cómo arreglo esta regex para que realice correctamente estos reemplazos de cada uno de los elementos de una lista dentro de una string?

```py
import re

list_to_find = [['1', '00', 'am'], ['1', '00', 'pm'], ['1', '', 'pm'], ['', '', 'pm'], ['5', '', 'pm']]
list_corrected = [['01', '00', 'am'], ['01', '00', 'pm'], ['01', '00', 'pm'], ['00', '00', 'am'], ['05', '00', 'pm']]

input_text = "el cine esta abierto hasta 23:30 pm o 01:00 am, 01:00 am 01:00 pm, : p m, 1: pm  5  pm"


n=0
for elem_to_find in list_to_find:

    #civil_time_pattern = r'(\d{1,2})[\s|:]*(\d{0,2})\s*(am|pm)?'
    civil_time_pattern = str(elem_to_find[0]) + r"[\s|:]*" + str(elem_to_find[1]) + r"\s*" + str(elem_to_find[2])
    civil_time_pattern_fix = ( str(list_corrected[n][0]) + ":" + str(list_corrected[n][1]) + " " + str(list_corrected[n][2]) ).strip()
    print(repr(civil_time_pattern))
    print(repr(civil_time_pattern_fix))

    input_text = re.sub(civil_time_pattern, civil_time_pattern_fix, input_text, 1) #Configuré solo un reemplazo por iteración en orden de izquierda a derecha
    n += 1

print(repr(input_text))
```

Este es el **output incorrecto** que me está retornando este código:

```py
'1[\\s|:]*00\\s*am'
'01:00 am'
'1[\\s|:]*00\\s*pm'
'01:00 pm'
'1[\\s|:]*\\s*pm'
'01:00 pm'
'[\\s|:]*\\s*pm'
'00:00 am'
'5[\\s|:]*\\s*pm'
'05:00 pm'
'el cine esta abierto hasta 23:3000:00 am o 001:00 am, 01:00 am 001:00 pm, : p m, 01:00 pm  05:00 pm'
```

¿Qué es lo que está fallando? O sea, ¿por qué sucede esto **23:3000:00 am**, esto **001:00 am** y esto **001:00 pm**?

Por cierto, este sería el output correcto que estoy necesitando:

```py
'el cine esta abierto hasta 23:30 pm o 01:00 am, 01:00 am 01:00 pm, 00:00 p m, 01:00 pm  5:00 pm'
```

Creo que el problema está en la regex, ya que debería establecer mejor la condición en la cual realizar los reemplazos. El problema es que se me está complicando demasiado establecerla.

```
civil_time_pattern = str(elem_to_find[0]) + r"[\s|:]*" + str(elem_to_find[1]) + r"\s*" + str(elem_to_find[2])
```

Comment: ¿Ttiene que ser con regex? Suena que se puede hacer bastante fácil con una función que tenga valores por default y que puedan ser reemplazables por los otros horarios haciéndoles un zero padding left a las horas y minutos.

Comment: @aeportugal No es realmente necesario que sea usando una identificación por medio de RegEx, a mi se me ocurrió hacerlo estableciendo un patrón RegEx porque creí que ese era el mejor modo de identificar aquel patrón en el que deben realizarse los reemplazos, pero realmente lo único que si se debe respetar es que los elementos de la lista **list_to_find** sean reemplazados en la string **input_text** , del modo en que se indica en el ejemplo, por los de la lista **list_corrected**.